# How to modify soap message parameters

Tags: soap

My current SOAP1.1 Message is working well and generating appropriate results. However, SOAP message is taking parameters as arg0, arg1, arg2... I want to pass parameters with tag names like, fName, lName, age,gender.

What changes I do need to make on my server side service to achieve this thing.

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
          <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"> 
               <S:Header/>
               <S:Body>
                   <ns2:getRelatedClassModels xmlns:ns2="http://service.accounting.cassit.com/">
                   <arg0 xsi:type=xsd:string>Aqif</arg0>
                   <arg1 xsi:type=xsd:string>hameed</arg1>
                    </ns2:getRelatedClassModels>
               </S:Body>
           </S:Envelope>
```

I want it to be like,

```
  <?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"> 
       <S:Header/>
       <S:Body>
           <ns2:getRelatedClassModels xmlns:ns2="http://service.accounting.cassit.com/">
           <fName>Aqif</fName>
           <lName>hameed</lName>
                    </ns2:getRelatedClassModels>
       </S:Body>
   </S:Envelope>
```

Comment: You can't arbitrarily change the message structure. It is what it is. But you've given us no context as to what any of this means, what software you're using, so the question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version=1.0 encoding=UTF-8?>
  <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"> 
       <S:Header/>
       <S:Body>
           <ns2:getRelatedClassModels xmlns:ns2="http://service.accounting.cassit.com/">
           <fName>Aqif</fName>
           <lName>hameed</lName>
                    </ns2:getRelatedClassModels>
       </S:Body>
   </S:Envelope>
```

This type of message structures are possible with SOAP v1.2 and above. I had to upgrade my SOAP version.